# how to get Image Array from NSDictionary in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, web-services

i want to get array of all images with recipe id and want to pass this array of images to next viewController but my problem is that i am getting only one image,i used recipeDC as entity class, for array of all images should i use another entity class or it can also be done by using same class, what should i do, i m stuck please help me,

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getAllRecipiesByUserId:(RecipeDC *)recipeid
{
    NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

     NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@get_all_recipies_by_user_id&user_id=%d",kWSURL,recipeid.user_id];


    NSDictionary * returnDict = (NSDictionary *) [self callWebService:url];
    if([returnDict objectForKey:@"response"])
    {
        NSDictionary * returnDictSuccess = (NSDictionary *) [returnDict objectForKey:@"response"];
        NSArray *returnedDealArray = [returnDictSuccess objectForKey:@"recipies"];

        RecipeDC *recpie = [[RecipeDC alloc] init];
        for(NSDictionary *dealDict in returnedDealArray)
        {

            recpie.recipe_id=[[dealDict objectForKey:@"recipe_id"]intValue ];
            recpie.category_id=[[dealDict objectForKey:@"category_id"]intValue ];
            recpie.user_id=[[dealDict objectForKey:@"user_id"]intValue ];
            recpie.recipe_name = [dealDict objectForKey:@"recipe_name" ];
            recpie.recipe_detail = [dealDict objectForKey:@"recipe_detail"];


            NSArray *img = [dealDict objectForKey:@"images"];

           for(NSDictionary *dealDict in img)
            {
               recpie.recipie_img_id=[[dealDict objectForKey:@"recipe_images_id"]intValue];
                recpie.recipe_id=[[dealDict objectForKey:@"recipe_id"]intValue];
                recpie.recipie_img_url=[dealDict objectForKey:@"image_url"];

           }
            [dataArray addObject:recpie];
        NSLog(@"arr count is %u",[dataArray count]);

        }
    }
    return dataArray;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done

```
RecipeDC *recpie = [[RecipeDC alloc] init];
    for(NSDictionary *dealDict in returnedDealArray)
    {
```

It should be

```
    for(NSDictionary *dealDict in returnedDealArray)
    {
       RecipeDC *recpie = [[RecipeDC alloc] init];
```

Inside the loop..

**Edited**
To get array of images you can save the whole dictionary of array you are doing

```
NSArray *img = [dealDict objectForKey:@"images"];

       for(NSDictionary *dealDict in img)
        {
           recpie.recipie_img_id=[[dealDict objectForKey:@"recipe_images_id"]intValue];
            recpie.recipe_id=[[dealDict objectForKey:@"recipe_id"]intValue];
            recpie.recipie_img_url=[dealDict objectForKey:@"image_url"];

       }
```

Instead, declare a property in RecipeDC class as NSArray *images; and just do the following

```
recpie.images=[dealDict objectForKey:@"images"];
```

Comment: i did .. can u tell me to get whole images in image array?